# как исправить ошибку в Джанго Запрещено (403). Проверка CSRF не удалась. Запрос прерван?

Tags: python, html, django

`** help in code the python **`

`form1`

```html
    <div class="registration-cssave">
    <form>
         <h3 class="text-center">Вход</h3>
        <div>
            <input  name="phone" type="phone" value="{{ phone }}" 
    placeholder="Телефон" readonly required>
        </div>
        <br>
          <input name="password"  type="text"  value="{{ random_num }}" 
     placeholder="Код пароль" readonly  required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Войти </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

`form2`

```html
    <form action="" method="post">
        <h3 class="text-center">Вход</h3>
        <div>
            <input type="phone" name="phone" maxlength="15" minlength="6" 
    pattern="^[0-9_.-]*$" placeholder="Телефон" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <a href="auth2.html">
            <input type="submit" value="Авторизация"/>
        </a>
    </form>
    </div>
```

`function`

```py
     def reg(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
           phone = request.POST["phone"]
           context = {'random_num': random_code(), 'phone': phone}
           return render(request, 'user_code/auth2.html', context)
```

`framework django, python`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `csrf_token` тег внутри ваших форм:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
</form>
```

Токен CSRF – это уникальное значение, которое сервер генерирует для защиты уязвимых перед CSRF атакой ресурсов. После выполнения запроса приложение на стороне сервера сравнивает два значения, найденные в сеансе пользователя и в самом запросе. Если токен отсутствует или не соответствует значению в сеансе пользователя, запрос отклоняется, сеанс пользователя завершается, а событие регистрируется как потенциальная атака CSRF.

[Здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/) вы подробнее можете почитать о работе CSRF защиты, реализованной в Django.

Comment: не помогает!!!!!